# Security implications of letting user call php methods

Tags: php

What are the risks associated with doing something like this? For instance, there may be some special characters that would pass the validations, allow the user to include unwanted files or make the php functions used here fail or not behave as intended, that I should be aware of.

```
//parse the uri
$uri=trim(parse_url(urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))['path'],'/');
$path=saferDirnameAndBasename($uri);
$class=$path->dir;
$method=$path->base;

//or it could be done with url rewritting, or just parameters, like:
//$class=$_GET['c'];
//$method=$_GET['m'];

$class=filter_var($class,FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW,FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW|FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$method=filter_var($method,FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW,FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW|FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

if(preg_match('/[^a-z0-9_\/-]/i',$class)||preg_match('/[^a-z0-9_]/i',$method)) exit;

$file=__DIR__.'/folder-where-public-clases-are/'.$class.'.php'; //note that it's allowing subdirs, but I don't want the user to go up
if(!file_exists($file)) exit;
include_once($file);

//remove the dashes too, my-class.php should contain myclass
$class=str_replace('-','',$class);

$path=saferDirnameAndBasename($class);
$namespace='\\publicClasses\\'.str_replace('/','\\',$path->dir); //dir/class -> \publicClasses\dir
$name=$path->base;
$fullname=$namespace.'\\'.$name;

if(!class_exists($fullname)) exit;
$obj=new $fullname;

if(!method_exists($obj,$method)) exit; //I know this doesn't account for visibility prior to php 7.4

call_user_func([$obj,$method]);

function saferDirnameAndBasename($path) {
    $parts=explode('/',$path);
    return (object)[
        'base'=>array_pop($parts),
        'dir'=>implode('/',$parts)
    ];
}
```

A file in `folder-where-public-clases-are` would cointain

```
<?php
    namespace publicClasses;
    class myclass {
        public function test() {
        }
    }
```

This would make a *dynamic* router, where the paths shouldn't be defined beforehand. Private code should just live outside the `publicClasses` namespace.

Comment: "What are the risks associated with doing something like this?" - **tremendous**.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Line 2 of your script has unverified user-input being passed directly into `dirname` - I gave up at that point. See here: https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/php-security-2/

Comment: Your script attempts to sanitize user-input for a filename with a regex, but it's straightforward to workaround most regex-imposed filters for filenames (hint: trigraphs). Your script is doomed. **DOOMED I TELL YOU!**

Comment: Well, it's not production code, I wrote it quickly to trigger this kind of answers. `dirname` and `basename` could easily replaced. The regexs were my main concern. Thank you.

Comment: I turned it into a class and created a repo in case anyone ever happens to feel like experimenting with it https://github.com/gquagliano/enrutador-dinamico (the comments are in spanish but the code is self explanatory).